# How to export multiple user to a file

Tags: linux, users, cut

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

id=`id -u`
if [ $id -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "eres root puedes continuar"
else
    echo "no eres root"
    echo "para continuar loqueate como root"
fi

for i in `cat secretaria.txt`
do
    id=`echo $i | cut -d ":" -f $1`
    contra="jblsony123"
    nombre=`echo $i | cut -d ":" -f2 $2`
    echo "$id:$contra:$nombre:/home/$id:/bin/bash" >> pablito.txt
    `chmod 777 temporal.txt`
done
```

```
43108863d:jblsony123:Caro:/home/4310863d:/bin/bash
Cabrera:jblsony123:Cabrera:/home/Cabrera:/bin/bash
43121847k:jblsony123:Caro:/home/43121847k:/bin/bash
Cronvall:jblsony123:Cronvall:/home/Cronvall:/bin/bash
Pedro:jblsony123:Petro:/home/Pedro:/bin/bash
43106680b:jblsony123:Castilla:/home/43106680b:/bin/bash
...
```

The problem I have is that I want to export the users from a text file to another file, adding other fields like password and group. I want than the first field is the dni.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux.  It's always better to copy and paste the text into the question (and format it with the `{}` button) rather than using images.

Comment: you might workaround awk solutions ```awk -F : '{print $1"-:-"$NF}' /path/file > /path/destinationfile``` you have to adapt it to fit your needs of course.

Comment: thanks a lot i will give it a try